# Very basic question about the definition of the derivative

Tags: calculus, limits, derivatives

[image]

Why is the definition of the derivative shown here as $\dfrac{\Delta x}{\Delta y}$ if immediately above the slope (derivative) is defined as $\dfrac{\Delta y}{\Delta x}$? Why is $\Delta x$ in the numerator in the second case, that confuses me...
Thank you.

Comment: I would assume it's a typo.

Comment: It's gotta be a typo.

Answer (score 3):

Just so someone formally answers this question.  It is a typo.  It should read:

definition of the derivative: $\cfrac{\Delta{y}}{\Delta x}$ of secant as $\Delta x \rightarrow 0$